# kibana-time-plugin downloaded but bower install not working and even kibana not working

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I wanted to have a Widget to view and edit the time range from within dashboards of kibana. So after lot of research i found a plugin as Kibana-time-plugin. Ref: https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin

Currently i am using kibana 5.4.0 in my local. After installing the plugin i have tried "bower install" as per the command specified in git page. But getting an error as :-

$ bower install

/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

And even if Kibana is not running and giving an error as below attached image:-
[kibana5.4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSRlv.png)

Can anyone Guide me on this ?

Thanks in Advance !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the optimization failures may be due to file permissions, the plugin files need to be accessible by the kibana user. Specifically check this instruction: 
[Installing plugins with linux packages](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/_installing_plugins.html#_installing_plugins_with_linux_packages)

Here is a complete script that worked for me. I am new to Kibana and Kibana plugins so any feedback appreciated. Two important notes:
1) I am pulling the zip file from S3 so you will need to edit that.
2) Be sure to restart kibana afterwards and check the logs

```
#!/bin/bash
# install nodejs and npm
sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g bower

# copy the plugin zip and unzip it and fix the name
cd /usr/share/kibana/plugins
sudo aws s3 cp s3://<YOUR-BUCKET>/kibana-time-plugin-master.zip .
sudo unzip kibana-time-plugin-master.zip
sudo mv kibana-time-plugin-master kibana-time-plugin

# install the plugin
cd /usr/share/kibana/plugins/kibana-time-plugin
sudo sed -i -e 's/5.0.0/5.4.2/' package.json 
sudo chown -R kibana:kibana *
sudo mkdir -p /home/kibana
sudo chown -R kibana:kibana /home/kibana
sudo -u kibana bower install
```